# How to parse large XML files with Nokogiri in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-parsing, nokogiri, large-files

I would like to parse large (2.2 GB) XML data files with Nokogiri.

If I do normal DOM parsing, surely the system will crash.

Is there best strategy for large XML files parsing with Nokogiri?

Comment: Use Nokogiri's [SAX parser](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX). SAX parsers can read arbitrarily large documents.

Comment: @theTinMan, I am going with nokogiri reader parser which will parse very large XML documents quickly without the need to load the entire document into memory or write a SAX document parser.